# Create a view that accepts a post request and performs an action regardless of if the instance has been created or not

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've got a view that takes in a phone number, and if the phone number isn't created, it'll send an SMS otp with `send_otp`. Now I want to also implement it so that if a phone number is sent to the endpoint but has already been registered to a user, then the view will send an otp all the same.

Right now, I get an error `"phone_number": ["user with this phone number already exists."]` when I try pass in a phone number for a user that already exists. How can I override this behaviour so the view doesn't check if the phone number is already registered to a user or not and just returns a `phone_number` json.

I have added breakpoints to `perform_create` , `save`, `create`, `update` methods but none of them get hit when I try pass in a phone number for a user that's already created

views.py

```py
class SendOTPCode(generics.CreateAPIView):
    
    permission_classes= [AllowAny]
    
    serializer_class= PhoneNumberSerializer
```

serializers.py

```py
class PhoneNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("phone_number",)
   
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        phone_number = self.validated_data['phone_number']
        send_otp(to_phone_number=phone_number)
        return None
```

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, unique = True, null = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the save function from the superclass, you must set the "force_insert" parameter to True. This instructs Django to create the user instead of updating an already-existing user in the database. In this manner, the phone_number field's unique constraint will be ignored, and the user will still be created even if the phone number belongs to another user.

```
class PhoneNumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("phone_number",)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        phone_number = self.validated_data['phone_number']
        send_otp(to_phone_number=phone_number)

        # ignoring phone_number field's unique constraint
        kwargs["force_insert"] = True
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```